# Node process.stdin Takes Multiple Key Strokes to Emit Data in Raw Mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, stdin, tty

I'm trying to catch every keystroke on standard in with Node 6.7.0. Here is what I am doing:

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('data', data);
}.bind(this));
```

When I run my program, I can press a key and it will log out `data d` but if I press multiple keys it only logs out a key after three total key presses. It's super weird. Anyone know what might be going on? I am using macOS Sierra terminal.

Comment: It seems like it's capturing "input". that means  the result   that keyboard driver provides for standard user input. Probably what you're looking for is to get somekind of keyboardMap function wich return the "still pressed keys" on every call

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for [Keyboard Events](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events)